# It is possible to do "if \(var1) = 0"?

Tags: swift, variables

```
var a = 0
```

(... up to var z = 0)

```
let letterchoosedbyplayer:String = LetterChoosed.text!
```

"LetterChoosed" is a textbox. The player enter a letter in this textbox. 
I store the value in the variable "letterchoosedbyplayer".
Then i want to check if the variable called 'letterchoosedbyplayer' (it must be a letter of the alphabet) is equal to 1.
How can i do that?
I want to do that :

```
if \(letterchoosedbyplayer) = 1 {          
}
```

Last Edit : All my code

```
let letterchoosedbyplayer:String = LetterChoosed.text!
if  Int(letterchoosedbyplayer) == 1 {
    print("vous avez perdu")
}
else {
switch letterchoosedbyplayer {

    case "a":
        print("lettre \(letterchoosedbyplayer) choisie")
        a = 1

    case "b":
        print("lettre \(letterchoosedbyplayer) choisie")
        b = 1

    default:
        print("cas défaut")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`\()` is used to append any object in a string. I don't think you can use this for your need
Try

```
if let letterchoosedbyplayer = LetterChoosed.text where letterchoosedbyplayer == "1" {
}
```

Comment: letterchoosedbyplayer store the value of Letterchoosed.text so it doesn't work, the if will be true every time

Comment: what you want to check actually?\

Comment: Iwant to check is the variable which name is contain in "letterchoosedbyplayer" is equal to 1. For example, the player enter the letter 'a' in the textbox. Then the variable called 'a' take the value of 1. Then I want the player to do not say the same letter in a party. It is the reason why i want to check if variable called 'a' is equal to 1

Comment: the you can try @vadian answer below

Answer (score 0):

You could include the `"1"` case in the `switch` statement:

```
let letterchoosedbyplayer = LetterChoosed.text
if let lettrechoisie = letterchoosedbyplayer where !lettrechoisie.isEmpty {
    switch lettrechoisie {
        case "1": print("vous avez perdu")
        case "a":
            print("lettre \(lettrechoisie) choisie")
            a = 1

        case "b":
            print("lettre \(lettrechoisie) choisie")
            b = 1

        default:
            print("cas défaut")
    }
 }
```

Note that `Int(letterchoosedbyplayer)! == 1` and `letterchoosedbyplayer == "1"` is the same thing.

**Edit:**

For your purpose you might use a dictionary rather than more than 20 single variables

```
var letterDict : [String : Int] = ["a" : 0, "b" : 0, "c" : 0, ... "z" : 0]
```

You can set a variable to `1` for example

```
letterDict["f"] = 1
```

Then you can check

```
if let lettrechoisie = letterchoosedbyplayer where !lettrechoisie.isEmpty {
    let value = letterDict[lettrechoisie]!
    if value == 1 { 
      // do something
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
}
```

That avoids also a huge `switch` statement.

Comment: It doesn't work, i want to check if every letter has already the value of 1.